# How to use tap gesture in Accessibility in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer, tap, uiaccessibility

I'm working on app for blind people first i needed to use swipe gesture and after search i can do it by using

```
 override func accessibilityScroll( direction:       
 UIAccessibilityScrollDirection)-> Bool {
 if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.Left
 {
   Do what you want to do 
   }
 }
```

Now I need to use tap gesture and I can't find any function to use make custom tap in Accessibility can anyone help me pleasee!
Thanks

Comment: Add UITapGestureRecognizer to your target view.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tap gesture for `UIAccessibility` ot try to add tap gestures to UIAccessibility.`UIAccessibility` is meant for the `UIElements` where the people can see/hear what is on the screen. You cannot add UIAccessiility for tap gesture functions. What you can do is to post a accessibility notification to the user saying tap to perform something. Again, you need to use buttons to perform an action in `UIAccessibility`.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `accessibilityScroll` method:

```
override func accessibilityScroll(_ direction: 
    UIAccessibilityScrollDirection) -> Bool {

    super.accessibilityScroll(direction)

    if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.left {
    // do your stuff            
    }

    if direction == UIAccessibilityScrollDirection.right {
    // do your stuff        
    }
    return true
}
```